# Why did my coppa get spicier after being microwaved?

Tags: food-science, microwave, sausages, spicy-hot

I wanted to put some spicy, crispy, crumbled [coppa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capicola) over a pasta dish. I put it in the microwave and it crisped up very well. It was however much spicier after cooking than before.

Why did it get spicier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The microwave caused heat which released oils from the coppa's spice blend, including capsaicin.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is water evaporated from the coppa and the flavors got more concentrated as a result. The same thing happens when you cook tomatoes, for example. They develop a stronger taste as a result of the water being evaporated during cooking.